# Why my computer check the whole data after restart

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc

I am using superspeed cache.

Other computers also use superspeed with no problem.

Also I often got message that this dll not working that dll not working. I often have to reinstall dropbox firefox and office.

I do not set the C drive for late write. Even if it's a problem, it wouldn't be like this. The reason is because drive C contains program and those dll is very rarely rewritten.

The drive D that has late write feature don't have this problem.

I scanned the C and D drive and no bad sector is fine.

Usually programs run just fine before restart. Something happen during restart that mess things up.

Comment: Are you asking why ChkDisk is running on startup? If not, what do you mean by "check the whole data" (what software is doing what - show some text)?

Comment: Yea. When things go right it doesn't (or do it very quickly). Now almost every time I run the computer for a long time and then restart my computer think that there is problem to be solved.